# unable to detect wireless after installing ubuntu 16.10: Broadcom bcm43212

Tags: networking, broadcom, 16.10

Can anyone help me in fixing my wireless adapter after i have installed ubuntu 16.10. I tried lspci and got the following details:

My network controller is: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b

Am i supposed to use kdiswrapper can get the wireless driver installed?
Did anyone face this issue and has solved it?

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `dkms` and `broadcom-sta-dkms`.

In `terminal`...

- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install dkms broadcom-sta-dkms`
- `reboot`

During the reboot, enter your BIOS and disable `secure boot`.

Comment: Why do you keep answering duplicate questions?

Comment: @Pilot6 I looked at the (lengthy text)  link that you refer to in your comment, and the answers are from 2011, and don't apply in this case (BCM43142). I recommend a more current/correct dkms driver. Also, when I look at many questions with a "duplicate of" link, the text sometimes doesn't answer the **specifics** of the **current** question. Lastly, as much as you may not like this, I don't gain any rep by taking **my time** researching through all of the possible search hits to determine a possibly appropriate/accurate duplicate answer, and posting that into a comment.

Comment: They DO apply to  BCM43142. This question is asked a few times a day.

Comment: @Pilot6 **Your** link wasn't one of them. Hence my point about "dup of" answers that don't address the **specifics** of the **current** question.

Comment: @Pilot6 ps: and if this question IS being asked a few times a day, then we aren't educating our readers of how to properly use the search features.

Comment: What do you mean by "my link was not one of them"? `lcpci -nn` will show that BCM43142 is `[14e4:4365]`

Comment: But [14e4:4365] wasn't given in the OP, and in your link, that ID calls out the bcmwl-kernel-source driver, which is NOT what I'm calling out.

Comment: OP should have run the script offered by `wireless`tag and find out the ID.  We try to do all to help people find this solution. But they keep asking. Nothing can be done.

Comment: @Pilot6 and that's **exactly** why I just answer the question. It's faster for both the OP and me.

Comment: OK. I agree....

Comment: @Pilot6 is there a written policy documenting how we should handle duplicates?

Comment: You can search meta or ask there a question. Exactly duplicate answers are discouraged and deleted.

Comment: @Pilot6 meta what? URL please.

Comment: http://meta.askubuntu.com/